# Getting "Dababase is locked" while using NHibernate over SQLite (multi-processes without transactions)

Tags: c#, sqlite, nhibernate

I'm using Nhibernate over SQLite to read 10 tables at the same time from many processes.
Even that I don't use transactions to do this, I'm still getting "Database is locked". Every table reading disturbed the other one in a different process.

I created a simple application in C# which uses System.Data.SQLite in order to reproduce the problem. But everything worked perfect.
The problem is only when I use NHibernate.

Does anyone know what can be the problem here? 
Thanks for any help.

Comment: Not sure if it is helpful for you but I had the same problem (without using NHibernate). I ended up using a `ReaderWriterLockSlim` which allows multiple readers but only one writer

Answer (score 1):

You have not provided configuration code; so it is hard to guess. What is the `IsolationLevel` you have set? Setting it to `ReadCommitted` should resolve the issue.

With Config-By-Code, it can be set as below:

```
configuration.SetProperty(NHibernate.Cfg.Environment.Isolation, "ReadCommitted");
```

With XML configuration, it can be set as below:

```
<hibernate-configuration xmlns="urn:nhibernate-configuration-2.2">
    <session-factory>
        <property name="connection.isolation">ReadCommitted</property>
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Alternatively, you can set it while beginning transaction as below:

```
session = SessionFactory.CreateSession();
transaction = session.BeginTransaction(isolationLevel);
```

[This](https://nhibernate.info/doc/nhibernate-reference/transactions.html) may be useful to you.